# Neo4j Benchmark

Tags: performance, benchmarking, neo4j

Does anyone know a simple benchmark for neo4j?

I tried to build it by myself but it spends 1s to create 1 node.. maybe it isn't the right way to build it!

Comment: @@ only in ms ,i use cypher

Comment: Are you using neo4j solo or in combination with spring data?
I had similar effects using the @Fetch annotation in the wrong places.

Answer (score 2):

A generic benchmark is always difficult as it is not representing your domain.

Some general tips:

- put enough operations (`createNode, createRelationship`) in the transactions 1k - 5k - 20k are good fits
- use -server
- give Neo4j enough heap-memory for your use-case
- run several rounds in a single benchmark, probably discard the first one and measure the others (to accomodate for JIT and Neo4j warmup)

What are your machine specs?

You can also have a look at these [benchmarks](https://github.com/neo4j/performance-benchmark) which are used for performance regression testing.

Comment: I have tried to use that bench, but I'm not able to let it work... I don't know why.. I have this server: http://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/eg_ssd.xml

Comment: Nice server btw. that one should rock with Neo4j :) Btw. please do also share your JVM heap memory configuration and startup parameters. You might also send me your databasedirectory/messages.log after your test run (includes all the diagnostic information).

Answer (score 0):

That may be because you instantaniated GraphDatabaseService and the created the node.
Simply creating a node on an instantaniated GraphDatabaseService will take lesser time.

Answer (score 0):

I think @MichaelHunger hit the nail on the head. If you're taking about a second to write a single node, you have way to many transactions.

Have you looked at Batch Inserts?

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html

Answer (score 0):

Just today, a new benchmark was released. For now, there are two graph databases in it, Neo4j and Memgraph. In the blog post, there is a link to GitHub repository and the methodology. Maybe it will be of help to you.

A blog post is located at https://memgraph.com/blog/memgraph-vs-neo4j-performance-benchmark-comparison.